# Macbook Pro: all apps crashing?

Tags: macbook-pro, high-sierra, performance

I have a 2017 MacBook Pro running macOS High Sierra. Today, System Preferences app suddenly stopped responding, followed by every other app whenever I had them active. Force quitting them was useless, since they would freeze once I re-opened them. Even the Mac toolbar froze when I had my cursor on it, preventing me from restarting my Mac from the menu.

I held down the power button to restart it, but the problem repeats upon reboot. Not just apps, but notifications, the touch bar, and spotlight inevitably freeze. Console crashes whenever I open it, so I can't get info out of it. Activity Monitor briefly shows that the CPU load is very high, before it crashes itself.

I've already tried resetting the NVRAM and SMC. How do I resolve the issue?

Comment: Did you try reinstalling the operating system from Recovery? Doing this will not remove any personal files or 3rd party applications. It will only reinstall the operating system and won't touch your files.

Comment: @pixelomer I realize I wasn't logged in when I wrote this question. Your comment helped temporarily, but now some apps are still freezing. I figured out that they only freeze when I have my cursor on them; only a few like Safari seem work in that case. Any advice?